# PostGIS crosstab on multiple point tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I have several point tabels, lets say 3. Tables are alike with two columns: a integer value and a geometry like:

- table sand1 (value int, geom geometry)
- table sand2 (value int, geom geometry)
- table sand3 (value int, geom geometry)

I need to join the three tables to a new table with four columns like:
valueTab1, valueTab2, valueTab3, geometry.

The join has to be on the point geometry. The value field cannot be used since it is a measurement value. Some of the points are positioned directly on top of each other. The ST_Equals points then results in one record.

[image]
So the picture above with three layers sand1 (three records), sand2 (two records) and sand3 (three records) should produce a new table with four columns and four records.

Columns:

```
sand1Value, sand2Value, sand3Value, geom
```

---

Records:

```
22, null, null, null, geom 
null, 31, 37, null, geom 
1111, null, 66, geom 
11, 44, 55, geom
```

I have tried joining with ST_Equals(sand1.geom, sand2.geom), but ST_Equals does only take two parameters. Have tried the tablefunc extension with crosstab and multiple joins on like WHERE ST_AsText(sand1.geom) IN (ST_AsText(sand2.geom), ST_AsText(sand3.geom))

Comment: Are these points the could be anywhere, like GPS coordinates from a cell phone? Or points that correspond to a limited number of known locations, like weather stations?

Comment: This is a fun one. I have managed to join tables using union select and then doing a spatial self join with union but somewhere in my array_agg(distinct(concat(sand1.val, sand2.val.....) the nulls are getting eaten up. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Does the point always exist in all the tables and it is simply value that may or may not exist. Or might there be missing points also? If the former, then neighdough's answer is correct, otherwise, it is much more complicated.

Comment: @Lee Hackadoorian: The points are generated from a groundwater modelling tool. The value [mm / year] is groundwater added to a reservoir in a sand layer at that given point. If sand1, sand2 and sand3 have common points they have the exactly same (x,y)

Comment: @John Barça: I believe the union select and a spatial self join is a good way. This puts all the geometries in one table. I will look into this. The number of points varies between the three tables. If only sand1 and sand2 have a commen point, the value for sand3 should be null.

Comment: I used ST_Union rather than ST_Equals and a where a.id != b.id using row_number() over() from the table created in the union select clause. Everything ended up in the same row, but, I had an array containing the concatenated values from the 3 columns, which varied from 1 to 3, based on how many times the geom existed in the 3 test tables, not in a nice 3 column layout as you want. So near, so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first `UNION` all the geometries.
Then you can `LEFT JOIN` the geometries `ON ST_Equals` to retrieve the values.

Sample code

```
-- Create dummy test values
WITH
sand1 AS
( SELECT val, ST_MakePoint(x, y) geom
  FROM (VALUES (11, 0, 0), (22, 1, 2), (32, 3, 1)) a(val, x, y) ),
sand2 AS
( SELECT val, ST_MakePoint(x, y) geom
  FROM (VALUES (12, 0, 0), (23, 1, 3), (33, 3, 1)) a(val, x, y) ),
sand3 AS
( SELECT val, ST_MakePoint(x, y) geom
  FROM (VALUES (17, 0, 0), (27, 1, 3), (37, 3, 4)) a(val, x, y) )

SELECT
  -- Rename columns
  sand1.val val1,
  sand2.val val2,
  sand3.val val3,
  ST_AsText(all_geoms.geom) geom_txt
FROM
-- UNION all geometries from the three tables
(
SELECT geom FROM sand1
UNION
SELECT geom FROM sand2
UNION
SELECT geom FROM sand3
) all_geoms
-- Join back the geometries when they are equal
LEFT JOIN
  sand1 ON ST_Equals(all_geoms.geom, sand1.geom)
LEFT JOIN
  sand2 ON ST_Equals(all_geoms.geom, sand2.geom)
LEFT JOIN
  sand3 ON ST_Equals(all_geoms.geom, sand3.geom);
```

Returns:

[image: Result]

Comment: Clever, left join on a merged geometry field.

Comment: As a concluding remark: I did a run on real data with 6 sand layer each with around 30000 records. It took 37 minutes on an old i5 laptop.

Comment: Indeed this query is not very optimized. Maybe it could run faster by first creating a table/matview with the unioned geometries, add a geometry index and then run the Left Joins.